# How to open specific post dropdown menu without effecting the others?

Tags: reactjs

I have data that I am looping through and I have a slight issue with a dropdown menu. Whenever I click the dropdown button for a single post all the other posts open. And I don't know to solve it.

**Here is the React code**

```
const Post = () {
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
return(
  {posts.map((post) => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={post.postId}>
              <div className="card-header">
                <div className="card-header__avatar">
                  <img
                    src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/40x40"
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="card-header__username">
                  <span>
                    <strong>
                      {post.firstname} {post.lastname}
                    </strong>
                  </span>
                  <br />
                  <span>
                    <small>{date}</small>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div
                  className="card-header__moreBtn"
                  onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
                >
                  <img src={More} alt="" />
                  {open && ( ------> here is where the problem comes
                    <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-menu__item">
                          <Link href="#d" onClick={deletePost}>Edit</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-menu__item">
                          <Link className="dropdown-menu__item__link" onClick={deletePost}>Delete</Link>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="postDescription">
                <p>{post.postDescription}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="imgPost">
                <img src={post.image} alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
  )
}
```

**Here is a picture**
[image: image of that shows how when clicked the dropdown menu for a specific post all of the other effects]

Any help will suffice and I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same state value for all items in your loop, so naturally they are going to all follow the same directive.

I would recommend creating a `PostItem` component that maintains its own state.  Something like this:

```
const PostItem = ({post}) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
    return (
      <div className="card" key={post.postId}>
        <div className="card-header">
          <div className="card-header__avatar">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/40x40"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
          <div className="card-header__username">
            <span>
              <strong>
                {post.firstname} {post.lastname}
              </strong>
            </span>
            <br />
            <span>
        <small>{date}</small>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div
            className="card-header__moreBtn"
            onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
          >
            <img src={More} alt="" />
            {open && (
              <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="dropdown-menu__item">
                    <Link href="#d" onClick={deletePost}>Edit</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-menu__item">
                    <Link className="dropdown-menu__item__link" onClick={deletePost}>Delete</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="postDescription">
          <p>{post.postDescription}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="imgPost">
          <img src={post.image} alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  })
}

const AllPosts = ({posts}) {
return(
  {posts.map(post => <PostItem post={post} />
  )
}
```

Now each `PostItem` has a separate, internal instance of `open` in its own state and will act independently from the others.